# AVD is not starting (Segmentation fault (core dumped) Ubuntu 12 64 bit

Tags: android, ubuntu-12.04

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit with Android SDK Tools 21 and Android 4.2.2(API 17).

Following error i am getting:

```
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '32m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '213'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/home/eparrao/.android/avd/myavd.avd/cache.img
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`enter code here`
```

Please can anyone help on this

Answer (score 2):

I was running into the same issue today, seems a recent update of the SDK broke some things, quick fix is to run this in a terminal:

```
$ cd $ANDROID_SDK/tools/lib
$ mv libOpenglRender.so libOpenglRender.so.bak
```

Source: www.aguasnegras.es/blog/?p=524

Comment: For 64 bit remove the lib64OpenglRender.so file. Spent an hour debugging this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use Command

emulator-arm @name_of_virtual_device

Hope this helps :)